# php execution timeout on every laravel request with database call

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, laravel-5

I have local development environment setup with xampp, and am with working laravel 5.2 and php5.6.3.
Making a request to route without a database operation runs without any issues, but trying accessing the db with an eloquent model results in

```
Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded
```

at different points in the execution of database operation.
This is the error log

```
[2016-04-25 02:57:56] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded' in C:\xampp\htdocs\pscosmetics\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:539
Stack trace:
#0 {main}  
[2016-04-25 03:05:57] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded' in C:\xampp\htdocs\pscosmetics\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Str.php:89
Stack trace:
#0 {main}  
[2016-04-25 03:08:51] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded' in C:\xampp\htdocs\pscosmetics\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php:834
Stack trace:
#0 {main}  
[2016-04-25 03:11:04] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded' in C:\xampp\htdocs\pscosmetics\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:539
Stack trace:
#0 {main}  
[2016-04-25 03:35:59] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded' in C:\xampp\htdocs\pscosmetics\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation.php:204
Stack trace:
#0 {main}  
[2016-04-25 03:40:42] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded' in C:\xampp\htdocs\pscosmetics\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php:834
Stack trace:
#0 {main}  


Trying the same db operation using vanilla php and PDO works without a hitch, phpMyadmin works ok.
What could cause this sort of issue?.
```

Comment: What calls is your script timing out on exactly?

Comment: @Chris database calls...i updated the question with my error log

Comment: @MrFoh Please post the controller that make the call to db?

Comment: post your tried code, So we can make decision, it seems that you are trying to fetch too much records (from DB) at single time. thats why PHP execution time exceeds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of digging around error stack traces, i figured out the issue was with Eloquent eager loading.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entities;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ['parent_id', 'name', 'slug', 'description', 'keywords'];

   /**
   This is what was causing the timeouts as it had it's own nested relationships
    */
   protected $with = ['products']; 

    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Entities\Product', 'category_id');
    }
}
```